# How to Convert 4-Byte Array to Integer in php?

Tags: php, type-conversion

How to Converts a 4-Byte Array to Integer array.

```
<?php
$i = "A\0\0\0\A\0\0\0\A\0\0\0";  //I think this input 12Byte Array
$j = unpack("i*",$i); //I want this output 65,65,65 (4Byte * 3)
?>
```

is not working code..

how can i get the output

```
   $j[0]=65, $j[1]=65, $j[2]=65 ?
```

Comment: Or.. if $i need change, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

The above code is not working due to the fact that you're trying to reference a variable that wasn't defined:

```
$i = "A\0\0\0\A\0\0\0\A\0\0\0"; 
$j = unpack("i*",$i); //$i here, not $j
```

The output that comes from this is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 65
    [2] => 16732
    [3] => 4283392
)
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#l8MwH6euw)

Comment: thank you for reply... $j is my mistake,  I hope that $j[2] value not 16732, but 65.!